# Python: How to add a secondary x axis for a single trace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I have a DataFrame (see 'Test Data' section below) and I would like to add a secondary x axis (at the top). But this axis has to be from 0 to 38.24(ms). This is the sum of all values in column 'Time'. It expresses the total time that the 4 inferences took to execute.
So far I have tried 'twinx()' without success.

How can I do that? Is it possible or am I lacking information?

#### Test Data:

```
raw_data = {'Time': [21.9235, 4.17876, 4.02168, 3.81504, 4.2972],
            'TPU': [33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3],
            'CPU': [32, 32, 32, 32, 32],
            'MemUsed': [435.92, 435.90, 436.02, 436.02, 436.19]}

df_m=pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Time', 'TPU', 'CPU', 'MemUsed'])

df_m
```

```
##Sum of all values in column Time(ms)
(df_m.iloc[:, 0].sum())

##Time per inference(ms)
ax = df_m.plot(kind = 'line', y = 'MemUsed', grid = True)
ax.set_xlabel("NUMBER OF INFERENCES")
ax.set_ylabel("MemUsed(MB)")
```

#### What I have tried:

```
ax = df_m.plot(kind = 'line', y = 'MemUsed', grid = True)
df_m.plot(kind='line', ax=ax.twinx(), secondary_x=range(0, 39))
ax.set_xlabel("NUMBER OF INFERENCES")
ax.set_ylabel("MemUsed(MB)")
```

#### Output Graph:

[image]

How does the big table look like

[image]

Comment: Is plotly an option?

Comment: Sure. I have never used though. But the graphs seem to be very beautiful.

Comment: Excellent. I agree, plotly graphs can be quite stunning. I've popped an answer on for you and upvoted the question for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to your positive comment regarding plotly, here is an example of how to achieve a multi-xaxis for your dataset.

The code is a lot simpler than it looks. The code appears 'lengthy' due to the way I've formatted the `dict`s for easier reading.

The key elements are:

- Adding a cumulative sum of the `time` column (`time_c`) for use on `xaxis2`.
- Adding a hidden trace which aligns to `xaxis`, and your time data which aligns to `xaxis2`. Without the hidden trace, either both axes do not appear, or they appear but are not aligned, due to only one trace being plotted.

#### (Updated) Sample Code:

The following code has been updated to address the issue OP was having with a larger (70k row) dataset.

The key change is an update to the `layout['xaxis']` and `layout['xaxis2']` dicts to contain `'type': 'category'`, `'nticks'` and defined `'range'` keys.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import plot

# Create the dataset.
raw_data = {'time': [21.9235, 4.17876, 4.02168, 3.81504, 4.2972],
            'tpu': [33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3],
            'cpu': [32, 32, 32, 32, 32],
            'memused': [435.92, 435.90, 436.02, 436.02, 436.19]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df['time_c'] = df['time'].cumsum().round(2)

# Plotting code.
data = []
layout = {'margin': {'t': 105},
          'title': {'text': 'Example Showing use of Secondary X-Axis', 
                    'y': 0.97}}

# Create a (hidden) trace for the xaxis.
data.append({'x': df.index,
             'y': df['memused'],
             'showlegend': False,
             'mode': 'markers', 
             'marker': {'size': 0.001}})
# Create the visible trace for xaxis2.
data.append({'x': df['time_c'],
             'y': df['memused'],
             'xaxis': 'x2',
             'name': 'Inference'})

# Configure graph layout.
nticks = int(df.shape[0] // (df.shape[0] * 0.05))
layout['xaxis'] = {'title': 'Number of Inferences',
                   'nticks': nticks,
                   'range': [df.index.min(), df.index.max()],
                   'tickangle': 45,
                   'type': 'category'}
layout['xaxis2'] = {'title': 'Time(ms)', 
                    'nticks': nticks,
                    'overlaying': 'x1', 
                    'range': [df['time_c'].min(), df['time_c'].max()],
                    'side': 'top', 
                    'tickangle': 45,
                    'type': 'category'}
layout['yaxis'] = {'title': 'Memory Used (MB)'}

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': layout}
plot(fig, filename='/path/to/graph.html')
```

#### Example Graph (original dataset):

I've intentionally left out any additional appear configuration for code simplicity. However, referring to the top level [plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python/), the graphs are **highly** configurable.

[image]

#### Example Graph (new dataset):

This graph uses the (larger, 70k row) synthesised dataset from the other answer.

[image]

Comment: I have problems when using a big dataframe

Comment: That might be because the data is actually getting plotted twice; I think I have a solution.  Is the dataset similar to what you have posted in the question?  How many rows? I have an idea for a different xaxis approach.

Comment: Yes, it is similar. I will put an image. There are 70000 rows

Comment: There we go. I've updated the code and graphs in the original answer to address the issue you're having. Additionally, I've posted a second answer (sshhhh) to give you another option, which removes the need to plot *two* traces of 70k data point each. Hope this helps!

Comment: It has worked. It is faster. I will analyze your code.

Answer (score 1):

Although generally discouraged, I'll post another answer to address the new dataset, as the previous answer works, given the original dataset.

This example diverges from the original request of a secondary x-axis for two reasons:

1. Due to the size of the (new) dataset, plotting a 'hidden' layer of data is not optimal.
2. For a secondary x-axis to display properly, a second trend must be plotted, and given the previous reason, this is no longer an option.

Therefore, a different approach has been taken - that of **combined labeling** of the x-axis. Rather than plotting two axes, the single x-axis features both required labels.

#### Example Graph:

Note: This is (obviously) synthesised data, in order to achieve the number of rows (70k) in the updated question.

[image]

#### Sample Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import plot

# Synthesised dataset. (This code can be ignored.)
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.exponential(size=70000)*4
t = pd.Series(a).rolling(window=2000, min_periods=50).mean().to_numpy()
r = np.arange(70000).astype(str)
m = t*100

df = pd.DataFrame({'run': r, 
                   'time': t,
                   'memused': m}).dropna()

# Add cumulative time column.
df['time_c'] = df['time'].cumsum().round(1)


# --- Graphing code starts here ---

def create_labels(x):
    """Function to create xaxis labels."""
    return f"({x['run']}): {x['time_c']}"

# Create xaxis labels.
df['xaxis'] = df.apply(create_labels, axis=1)

# Create the graph.
data = []
layout = {'title': 'Combined X-Axis Labeling'}
data.append({'x': df['xaxis'], 
             'y': df['memused']})

layout['xaxis'] = {'title': '(Inference): Cumulative Time (ms)', 
                   'type': 'category', 
                   'nticks': df.shape[0] // 3500,
                   'tickangle': 45}
layout['yaxis'] = {'title': 'Memory Used (MB)'}


fig = {'data': data, 'layout': layout}
plot(fig, filename='/path/to/graph.html')
```